# css put button within form after other block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have such html code:

```
<div class="actions">
   <input id="submit-car" name="commit" type="submit" value="Добавить объявление">
</div>
```

and fiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/348U4/

as you can see i have submit button "Добавить объявление" in form... But how can i set it within form, after `.car-photo` block?

I have some ideas:

- put absolute position: but so, i didn't know height of .car-photo and could have button on block `car-photo`
- i add second submit after `car-photo` and put js, which click on hidden normal submin in form - but have some troubles in IE.

How could i normally do this thing? How to view button within form, which work's?

Comment: A question should contain enough code to reproduce the issue. Here also a small fragment is given, and the text of the question refers to something that is not present in that fragment.

Comment: You are saying that you have a button “in [a] form” and that you need to “set it within [the] form”. Please clarify what you mean (and try to present a *reduced* example, in the question itself).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela   all is in fidle, also all is clear... submit button not in form. this button must reffer to first form, not to form in car-photo

Answer (score 0):

You could move `car-photo` into the form.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/348U4/1/

Comment: this button must reffer to first form, not to form in car-photo

Comment: Oh I see. The submit button would be in the form but your `{%` is breaking the whole html in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

As I correctly understand. You need using tag `<button>` It can be used within the form tag

Comment: this button must reffer to first form, not to form in car-photo

Comment: @brabertaser1992 So what's the problem. It can be reffered for every form in the page.

Comment: i have two form's, and how in would be submited? form in form? this is bad